# Unknown piece of code, what's it called?

Tags: c#

I saw this in a random doxygen example for C#, and all attempts at Googling for it have failed since I have no idea what it's called or what it does.

```
int test(int a, string b);       
int i = test(1, "b");
```

Any one have any insight?

EDIT

So here's a fun try. I put it into a new program and it doesn't compile, except if I put a static in front of it. Now it compiles.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int test(int a, string b);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = test(1, "b");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you link the page? anyway this looks a lot like a simple example...

Comment: What do you want to know? You have a method signature and an example call. There is nothing more to be said about the code you posted.

Comment: Why am I garnering minuses on my question? Is it because people don't know the answer and want to take it out on the asker?

Comment: Try to compile it and see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure this is C#?

Comment: CodeInChaos: How would you use this? How is it useful? How is it a method signature? I'm used to seeing like: public int test(int a, string b){}. If it were like that it would make more sense.

Comment: @Phil and BoltClock, yes, it is C#. If I put it into a solution it doesn't yell at me and even provides intellisense for the test method (if indeed that is what it is.) As for compiling it, nothing seems to happen. It doesn't yell at me, at the very least.

Comment: That doesn't look like real sourcecode. I can't think of a context where these two lines would compile. If you claim that it compiles, please post a compilable sample. It's just the method signature with an omitted body, since documentation usually doesn't contain the method body.

Comment: Is this the full code sample?

Comment: Please post the link to the original doxygen example.

Comment: Not even the version you posted now compiles. You can't have a method with no body inside a class.

Comment: I ran it in VS2010. Runs and compiles, but does nothing.

Comment: @JMD: Doesn't compile for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line looks like an interface declaration. It is saying that a class has a method that accepts an integer and a string and returns an integer.

Then it calls the method. However, this isn't valid right now. I'm not sure if the rest was removed for brevity since you didn't link to the source. Valid code would look like this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int test(int a, string b);       
}

ISomeInterface instance = GetInstance();

int i = instance.test(1, "b");
```

Comment: If I put it into code though it's not saying there is an error, which is what I would expect since I don't provide the method, and you can't call an interface directly.

Comment: I just assumed the rest was removed for brevity in whatever it is that you're reading. You didn't link to it. I was just trying to help.

Comment: @JMD I strongly doubt that this code compiles in any context.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, you can keep that thought to one section please, no need to bandy it about the life of the thread. I'm making a brand new program and testing it out now. If it doesn't work, then the Doxygen code is just wacky.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Updated answer with what valid interface code **might** look like.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's an interesting answer. Take a look at my updated question and see if it still makes sense.

Comment: @JMD, your new code doesn't compile either: I get: "'ConsoleApplication1.Program.test(int, string)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"

Comment: @ChrisBenard I also receive the same error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not real or not full code.

The code you posted will not compile for two reasons:

1.If you put it inside a method it will not compile because of the first line:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement.

2.If you put it outside a method it will not compile because of both lines:

> 'Test.Program.test(int, string)' must declare a body because it is not
>   marked abstract, extern, or partial.
>
> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Test.Program.test(int, string)'

**Edit**: Even the new code version fails to compile:

> 'Test.Program.test(int, string)' must declare a body because it is not
>   marked abstract, extern, or partial.

Comment: This is also the answer to why the question was downvoted.

Comment: I was asking what a piece of code might be called, not asking people to compile it. The same as some being like "what is a good way to check if a string is empty?" Oops, not full code, downvote.

Comment: @JMD: It is called non-compiling code.

Comment: Yes, but I asked what something is called, not help with why it won't work. That's like requiring a short story to answer that "run" is a verb.

Comment: @JMD: What do you mean what is it called? It's code that does not conform to the language. What other name are you expecting?

Comment: Seriously? I literally asked what the code "does or means" and your answer is "doesn't compile so whatever." That's, once again, like me being like "what type of word is run? what part of speech?" and you say "'run' isn't a full sentence so it doesn't conform to the language."

Comment: @JMD: How do you expect me to "interpret" a code that does not conform to the language? What am I supposed to tell you that it does since it will not pass compilation? That's like showing me a car with no engine and asking me how fast it can go. It doesn't have the ability to start!

Comment: I gave an example I saw somewhere and was asking if anyone knew what it did or meant. It doesn't need to compile, it's a snippet, incomplete or not, and if someone recognizes it, they should say something, if they don't they shouldn't bother wasting their time with it. Also, your car analogy is flawed because I was asking what something did, in your analogy we already know what a car does, its speed is irrelevant. It's more like showing you a car with no engine and saying "what is this thing?"